# How to control checkbox value on client side with mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have a problem. How to control checkbox value on client side with mvc, is this possible ? 
My used checkbox's value getting bool variable. Other guy changed with different value for example,

Original;

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="required place" id="Confirm" name="Confirm" required="required" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

TryToHack;

```
<input data-val="differentValue" data-val-required="required place" id="Confirm" name="Confirm" required="required" type="checkbox" value="differentValue">
```

Such that when throw exception, how to block this state with mvc ?

Comment: You may throw an error on $(document).ready(function(){
if($("input[required=required]").attr("data-val") != "true")
{
throw new Error("Your error message");
}
 });

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery. Value attribute shouldn't be bool, it can be text.

```
$('#Confirm').val(); //returns value of your checkbox
$('#Confirm').val("test"); //sets value to "test"
$('#Confirm').is(':checked'); //returns if checkbox is checked (true or false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may throw an error based on the attribute value as,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input[required=required]").attr("data-val") != "true")
    {
        throw new Error("Your error message");
    }
});
```